# Android cursor returns no rows for select-query

Tags: java, android, sql, cursor

i'm currently trying to get a single row from my own database, located in the assets folder. Checking if there is a row in the table, with the SQLite Query Browser and the SELECT-Statement from the debugger got me a single row in the database. Anyway calling the statement from my code just gets me an empty cursor. I also added the method

> cursor.moveToFirst()

and avoided calling

> myDataBase.close();

Here is the method where i'm trying to append a single entry on a TextView:

```
private void getAdresses(Location location) { // TODO
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lng = location.getLongitude();
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.GERMAN);

    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        if (addresses.size() != 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);

            String addressString = address.getAddressLine(0).toString();
            System.out.println("(geocoder) " + addressString);
            textView.append(addressString + "\n");

            Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.getAllEntrys("tblBar", "Adresse",
                    addressString);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                String cursorContent = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name"));
                textView.append(cursorContent + "\n");

            } else {
                System.out.println("No bar at current location");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("(geocoder) no address!");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString() + "(geocoder)");
    }
}
```

Furthermore this is my method for calling the actual query on the database:

```
public Cursor getAllEntrys(String table, String column, String search) {
    try {
        String sSelect = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + column
                + " = '" + search + "'";
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(sSelect, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        System.out.println("getData >>" + mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me with this. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try calling DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor) immediately after Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(sSelect, null); and check logcat for the dump. It will tell you if the cursor has anything in it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried dumping the cursor, it told me that my cursor has no content. Problem is i don't know why.

Comment: First make sure that the database is connected without problems. Then log sSelect before running the query. That will help you find mistakes in the query. You should be able to copy the log message right into your SQLite client without problems.

Comment: you should not use rawQuery. query is more likely to return anyhting

Comment: @Samuel: I did that this is the query: SELECT * FROM tblBar WHERE Adresse = 'Domplatz 3' i'm getting by logging at runtime, also i executed the query in the SQLite Browser and it returned a row with the expected data. Besides I'm running the debugger and watch the cursor object it provides me the columns from my database, but no row.

Comment: How are you connecting to the file through the SQLite Browser? You can't connect directly, right? Perhaps the file on the device and the file you're browsing are not the same. That's my last idea.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ so i can easily access the database file from the assets folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay guys first i want to thank all of you for your quick responses. Keep it up! Although the answer is quite obvious, i figured it out myself. The problem in the tutorial from: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/ is, that it doesn't consider the case that you add values manually (Updates in the SQLite Database Browser) to your database after you first run the programm. Thats what i did... So you have to write your own method to check if there were any changes since the last run. Hope anyone can need this :)

Answer (score 1):

//This works for me

```
final Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, LastName,RedId FROM " +
                SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                " where RedId =  '"+a+"'", null);
        int count = c.getCount();

        if(count == 0){

            Toast.makeText(RetrieveData.this, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for getting single row from your database.

Declare this method in your Database class.

```
 public Cursor selectSingleRecord(String tableName, String[] tableColumns,
        String whereClause, String whereArgs[], String groupBy,
        String having, String orderBy) {
    return myDataBase.query(tableName, tableColumns, whereClause, whereArgs,
            groupBy, having, orderBy);  

}
```

And use this method to get the cursor.

If my table structure is below.

> _id  | Name | Address

I will write in the following way

```
    String tableColumns[] = {"_id"}; // Here mansion the column which you want to retrieve I think in your case "addressString".
    String whereClause = {"Name"}; // Here use where clause

    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.selectSingleRecord("Your_Table_Name", tableColumns, whereClase +"=?" , new String[] {String.valueOf("NameOfPerson")}, null, null, null);

     // NameOfperson is the name which I am going to enter through EditText.
      if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {            
              String getId = cursor.getString[0];  // Here you can get the id of respective person (i.e. the name which I have entered )                          
         }
        cursor.close();  // Finally close the curser
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. i tried that, but it didn't work for me. Still getting an empty cursor.

Comment: String[] columns = {"_id", "Name", "Adresse", "Price_Beer", "Price_Liquor", "Price_Wine", "Longitude", "Latitude"};
    Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.selectSingleRecord("tblBar", columns, "Adresse" +"=?" , new String[] {String.valueOf(addressString)}, null, null, null); hope you can read it this way or should i post it in an new answer? also i added the method selectSingleRecord in my Databaseclass the same way you posted it.

Comment: have a look at my post I have made the necessary changes.I think this is quite good approach.Let me know is it works or not?

Comment: hey that was not the problem, have a look at my last post, it was a problem with updating a modified database. but thank you anyway!

Comment: In your question you asked how to get single row from database and I think I had explained that only thing?

Comment: no, my problem was that the cursor had no content and i didn't know why :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your sSelect to this: Sometimes in SQL it's better to use like 'something' than = something.

String sSelect = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + column
                + " like '" + search + "'";

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this might be the problem but . . .

```
String sSelect = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + column
                + " = '" + search + "'";
```

When your search variable is null, your query translates to :

> SELECT * FROM tblBar WHERE Adresse = 'null'

try to use this instead :

```
search = (search == null) ? " IS NULL " : " = '" + search +" '" ;

String sSelect = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + column + search;
```

Comment: thanks, but thats not the problem i'm getting the address i'm searching for from a geocoder object, and before executing the query i check if the given string is empty